# Put different types of C++ functions into one package

Tags: c++, templates, std-function, type-erasure

I have a simple idea: to package functions into a resource and retrieve
them directly from this resource when needed. As a result, I have the
following class (extremely simplified for illustration purposes).

```
class FunctionPackage {
public:
    void register_id(std::string name, std::function<void()> function) {
        functions[name] = function;
    }
public:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>> functions;
};
```

But this class can only store functions with fixed input and output types,
such as void(). I want to implement the functionality of storing various
types of functions, which may require some modifications to the class above.

```
class FunctionPackage {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void register_id(std::string name, T function) {
        functions[name] = function;
    }
public:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, ...> functions;
};
```

The definition of functions here may need to be diverse, or perhaps we need
to define a macro to implement runtime registration. At this point, I am
completely confused and cannot grasp any useful clues. I hope everyone can
help me with my problem. Thank you.

Comment: I suppose `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any>` would be a start. But if you go down that route there is no need for templates.

Comment: You will not be able to have functions with different signature stored in the same container in a sane way in C++. There are things like std::variant, but trying to build a dynamically typed system in a strongly typed language is just not a good idea. Just use C# or python or such, there are plenty to choose from.

Comment: What your `FunctionPackage` does looks a lot like the factory pattern, maybe read up on that for some ideas.

Comment: In order to make up your mind, write code using that package. That will help you get a better idea how it "feels" to use it. BTW: I don't know what you want to do with this, but consider the possibility that you're inventing something that is complete overkill for the actual task, i.e. that the effort invested is greater than the effort saved.

Comment: Even though you can hack it around with `std::variant` or `std::any`, don't do it. Better thing of a way to have a common function signature for your usecases. Input are integers but you don't know how many - `std::vector<int>`, number of inputs is fixed but sometimes not all are needed - `std::optional`.

Comment: Take a step back and ask yourself how you would retrieve and call these functions.

Comment: _"I want to implement the functionality of storing various types of functions, which may require some modifications to the class above"_ - The modification to the class is easy. The _use_ is where it becomes problematic.

Comment: what you ask for is type erasure. There is a common pattern with type erasure: Erasing the type is very simple, but restoring the type when needed is tricky. Hence, as others mentioned, you need to start by considering the use cases first. Then we can see if what you want is simple or impossible

Answer (score 0):

After going through the source code of [rttr](https://www.rttr.org/), I've gained a lot of inspiration. Now, tackling this issue is a breeze. I recommend all beginners to read rttr as well.

Comment: It's not particularly hard to implement, but the result is something that's hard to use. A function's type is fundamental to calling it, so why are you erasing that?